# Is it bad or not allowed to sleep after fajr?

Tags: hadith

My work schedule is basically from the evening until night. So when I come back after work it will be very late. So I prefer leaving for masjid very early before fajr and pray qiyam in masjid. And i sleep after fajr normally. Is it really bad to sleep after fajr? I heard it’s discouraged in Islam.

Answer (score 3):

https://islamqa.info/en/answers/2063/sleeping-after-fajr-and-asr

Praise be to Allaah.

As far as a person’s sleeping after praying Fajr is concerned, no text (of Qur’aan or hadeeth) has been reported to indicate that this is prohibited, so the general principle applies (i.e., everything is permitted except that which has been expressly forbidden).